# How to compute $=\sum_{k=0}^{r-1}\Big(\frac{-\alpha^{k}t^{k-1}}{(k-1)!}e^{-\alpha t}+\frac{\alpha^{k+1}t^k}{k!}e^{-\alpha t}\Big)$?

Tags: derivatives, gamma-distribution

When I read the derivation for finding the density function of the gamma distribution, I encountered this differentiation:

$$\frac{d}{dt}\Big(1-\sum_{k=0}^{r-1}\frac{(\alpha t)^k}{k!}e^{-\alpha t}\Big)$$
$$=\sum_{k=0}^{r-1}\Big(\frac{-\alpha^{k}t^{k-1}}{(k-1)!}e^{-\alpha t}+\frac{\alpha^{k+1}t^k}{k!}e^{-\alpha t}\Big)$$
$$=\frac{\alpha^{r}t^{r-1}}{(r-1)!}e^{-\alpha t}$$

The first step is just the product rule, what I don't quite get is the final step.

What I could do best is:

$$\sum_{k=0}^{r-1}\Big(\frac{-\alpha^{k}t^{k-1}}{(k-1)!}e^{-\alpha t}+\frac{\alpha^{k+1}t^k}{k!}e^{-\alpha t}\Big)$$
$$=\sum_{k=0}^{r-1}\frac{-\alpha^{k}t^{k-1}}{(k-1)!}e^{-\alpha t}+\sum_{k=0}^{r-1}\frac{\alpha^{k+1}t^k}{k!}e^{-\alpha t}$$
$$=e^{-\alpha t}\Big(\sum_{k=0}^{r-1}\frac{-\alpha^{k}t^{k-1}}{(k-1)!}+\sum_{k=0}^{r-1}\frac{\alpha^{k+1}t^k}{k!}\Big)$$

Could anyone please provide some explanation on how to compute the sum and get the final result? Thanks.

Comment: To find the last equality it might be useful to 'write out' the sum. You'll see terms that cancel out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not look completely right due to the index. In any case you can use the fact that you can write your series

$$
\sum_{k=0}^{r-1} a_{k}\mathrm{e}^{-\alpha t}-a_{k-1}\mathrm{e}^{-\alpha t} = \mathrm{e}^{-\alpha t}\sum_{k=0}^{r-1} a_{k}-a_{k-1}
$$
this is an example of a telescoping sum so only the boundaries survive i.e.
$$
\mathrm{e}^{-\alpha t}\sum_{k=0}^{r-1} a_{k}-a_{k-1} = \left(a_{r-1} - a_{-1} \right)\mathrm{e}^{-\alpha t}
$$
where 
$$
a_{k} = \frac{\alpha ^{k+1}t^{k}}{k!}
$$

$\textbf{appendix}$

$$
\sum_{k=0}^{r-1} a_{k}-a_{k-1} = a_0 - a_{-1} + (a_1- a_0) + (a_2 - a_1) +\cdots (a_{r-1}-a_{r-2})
$$
Re-arranging we can obtain
$$
-a_{-1} + (a_0-a_0) + (a_1-a_1) + \cdots + (a_{r-2} -a_{r-2}) + a_{r-1}  = a_{r-1} - a_{-1}
$$
As above.